# How can I ensure that my C# application can only read from the SQL Server databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building a C# application that runs/exports batches of Crystal Reports to PDF files. Some tests that I've done have shown that pushing the data to the report is much more efficient than letting the `ReportDocument` refresh it's own data.

I've found a way to extract the SQL from the Crystal Reports, and now I just need to safely execute the sql and bind the results back to the Crystal Report. My problem is that Crystal Reports have absolutely no built in checks to ensure that users aren't creating harmful Crystal Reports. You can create a Crystal Report, add a SQL Command Table, and provide the following as the "query":

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Test; SELECT * FROM tbl_Test
```

Crystal Reports won't see any problem with the above SQL. When you refresh the report, you'll lose all of the data in `tbl_Test`. The only limitation is the permissions of the sql user who is creating/running the report.

So, I need to make sure that my program isn't pulling/executing anything harmful. The best that I can come up with is to create a new user account on the SQL Server with read-only access to all databases and using this account to establish the connections within my application.

The problem with this is that I'm going to have my users log in with their existing SQL Server user accounts which each have their own existing permissions regarding which databases they have access to. I still need to limit what each user can view based upon their personal permissions, but some of these users have write-permissions to a number of databases, and I also need to make sure that any connection to any database from my application is 100% read-only.

Is there any way at all to establish a read-only connection to an SQL Server using the SQL Authentication of a user account that has permissions to insert/update/delete/etc.?

P.S. I am aware that any user with sufficient permissions/know-how/motivation could use Crystal Reports (...or any number of third-part applications, for that matter) to directly harm our databases. Right now I am more concerned about ensuring that my application can't be made into an unwitting accomplice. =P

Comment: Don't connect to the database with a user that has more than read access in the first place.

Comment: Why don't you create a schema or perhaps a role that you can put your users in, and then modify the table permissions. You'll only end up affecting the schema or role. That is.. if you really can't create a new user with more access than you would like.

Comment: We have a large number of databases, and each user account has varying permissions for each. I still need to ensure that all users are held within the bounds of their set permissions, but I also need to make sure that my application limits them to just read-only operations... even if another application that they use allows them to insert/update/delete. I can't just use a separate read-only account, as each user has specific permissions which limit which databases they have access to. I hope that helped clarify my possition.

Comment: If read-only is important, then you can't trust any application to enforce it. That must be enforced at the database server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THere is nothing forcing you to use the same connection for everything within the application.  Why don't you use a specific connection for this particular task.  That way you can leave all the existing user permissions the same but for this particular task create a new connection with a sql user that has only read only access to the required tables.  That way no dodgy SQL in the reports is going to do anything bad.

Comment: I like it. Is there a way to set up a user account to have read rights to all databases... even new ones that get added in the future? That's the last hurdle I ened to pass before things start going smoothly =P Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Not for future databases, but you could specify the securables for the "public" system role on each database including new ones, and then simply assign the public role to your reporting user.

Comment: I just thought of an issue with this method... If the read-only account has unlimited read-permissions to all databases, there's no way to validate if the logged-in user should be able to see the results of a report, which would have no restrictions as to the content. Would it be better to just temporarily alter the user account to add the readonly role, submit the sql, then remove them from the read-only role?